# Send exception information in soap response in Jboss 7

Tags: java, maven, soap, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

We are struggling here at the company to accomplish a requirement for our Maven project (jboss 7.1.1 , java 7) . 
We have a soap Webservice that exposes several methods . These methods throw exceptions . The exceptions are declared in a dependency of this project . The problem is we aren't able to send in the soap response any information regarding the kind of exception we throw in the webservice method . All the soap is bringing is

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
            <soap:Fault>
                <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
                <faultstring>MESSAGE</faultstring>
            </soap:Fault>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

The clients that are consuming our services can't tell wich kind of error they are getting . How can we overcome this issue ? How can we send in the soap body relevant information about the specific exception we are throwing ?

Our exception

```
    @WebFault
    public class OurException extends Exception
    {
        public OurException (){
            super();
        }


        public OurException (String message)
        {
            super(message);
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much,
Pedro Ferreira

Answer (score 0):

You can either convert your exception to the required response type and have an attribute that contains the information about your errors, or you can leverage the cxf SoapFault class which contains the method setDetail(Eelement detail).  With this you can construct your own xml Element and inject it into the SoapFault.

Hope that helps!